# Read files "$" data and bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I've created a script that sets up multiple Postfix easily and assigns a few things.

For example some of it is

```
postmulti -e init
postmulti -I postfix-$new -e create
echo "mydomain = $domain" >> /etc/postfix-$new/main.cf
    echo "queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix-$new" >> /etc/postfix-$new/main.cf
    echo "smtp_bind_address = $ip" >> /etc/postfix-$new/main.cf
    sed -i "s/oldip/$ip/g" /etc/postfix-$new/main.cf
    echo "/n*@$domain default._domainkey.$domain" >> /etc/opendkim/SigningTable
    sed -i "s/cyberciti.com/$domain/g" /etc/postfix-$new/main.cf
```

There are three requirements for this script `$new` `$ip` and `$domain`

The plan is to have lots of these in a file and bash the whole script which will run for each data line (see below)

```
new1, 1.1.1.1, myweb.com
new2, 2.2.2.2, myweb2.com
```

Seperated by `,` currently but I can set it to anything

How can I do this?

Comment: Note that `echo -e '...$...'` will cut off anything after the first `$`. You should drop the  `-e`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the separators in your data file to spaces.  You can usually avoid using commas — they are seldom beneficial in Unix systems.  Call the file `new_postfix_domains` (for sake of concrete discussion).

Write your script more or less along the lines of:

```
while read new ip domain
do
    config="/etc/postfix-$new/main.cf"
    postmulti -e init
    postmulti -I postfix-$new -e create
    echo "/n*@$domain default._domainkey.$domain" >> /etc/opendkim/SigningTable
    {
    echo "mydomain = $domain"
    echo "queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix-$new"
    echo "smtp_bind_address = $ip"
    } >> "$config"
    sed -i -e "s/oldip/$ip/g" \
           -e "s/cyberciti.com/$domain/g" "$config"
done
```

Run the script:

```
bash add_new_postfix_domains.sh < new_postfix_domains
```

Points to note:

1. The script combines the multiple outputs to the configuration file into a single sequence of operations with the `{ … } > "$config"` notation.  Be aware that `{` and `}` have slightly peculiar syntactic requirements.  The `{` must be a word on its own (surrounded by space), and `}` must be a word on its own where a command could start (e.g. at the beginning of a line, or after a semicolon).
2. You only need to edit the file once with `sed`.  I assume that the `postmulti … create` step created the config file with a template that needs editing.  Otherwise, the `sed` commands don't make any sense.
3. Use a variable to capture the config file name once; use the variable thereafter to refer to the file.
4. You should consider various forms of data validation.  For example, this will accept an empty line in the data and create an entry with blanks for the various components.  Maybe you should validate the IP address a little bit, and perhaps the domain name too.  If the data file might be screwed up, you might want to add an extra 'column' to the `read`: `read new ip domain junk` where the junk is captured in `$junk` and ignored (or reported before the line is ignored).
5. You might want to report what you're doing as you're doing it.
6. There will be those who argue that you should use `read -r` instead of just `read` so that screwball inputs are handled differently.  I don't think that's relevant here — [GIGO](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Garbage+In%2c+Garbage+Out) is reasonable if the people who'll use the script are supposed to be sane, and preferably knowledgeable.  You could pre-validate the input data if you chose.  For example, you could use `sed` to preprocess the input, ejecting any lines that don't match the 'three fields, middle field is an IPv4 address, last is a plausible domain name, first is an identifier with no inappropriate punctuation' requirement.
7. You could modify the script to read from a list of file name arguments, or from standard input if no names are provided on the command line.  That would be trivial if you pre-filter the inputs: `sed -e '…editing script…' "$@" | while read new ip domain` would do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `read` for this:

```
while IFS=', ' read -r new ip domain ; do
    ./your_script "$new" "$ip" "$domain"
done < input.file
```

Comment: @KenRenalds Replace the `./your_script` with `echo`, you'll see this very much does work. If the output is empty, it's because you have a bug in your script. It could have something to do with the `-e` in your `echo`es.

Comment: Ok I have removed that but it still didn't work with the following http://pastebin.com/PkQkJSca - Is it because of -e in the two postmulti commands ? What can I change that to?

Comment: I'll read it over and give it a go but I really don't think I will be able to do this myself - I am new to Linux and it took me several tedious hours just to get this small script

Comment: Don't worry, you can do it

Answer (score 0):

You need to export the variables to your script before you run it like:

```
while IFS=', ' read -r new ip domain ; do
    export new ip domain
    ./your_script
done < input.file
```

Or use hek2mgl's method of passing the values as arguments and add this to the beginning of your script:

```
new=$1
ip=$2
domain=$3
... #rest of script
```